# Stats - Expectation of distribution

Tags: statistics

For an exponential distribution, $X$ with parameter, $a$, the expectation is $\frac{1}{a}$. 
However, I'm not sure what the expectation of $X^4$ would be.
How would I find this?

Comment: Work from the definition of expectation, and you can calculate it as an integral. Use Integration by parts.

Comment: > For an exponential distribution, $X$ with parameter, $a$, the expectation is $\frac{1}{a}$ .......... Well, umm ... many would say that expectation is $a$ ... not $\frac{1}{a}$. All depends how you define your exponential distribution, and since there are multiple competing forms, you should really specify the functional form you are working with.

Comment: @wolfies *since there are multiple competing forms*... Really? You might want to provide examples of mathematical sources where the "parameter" of an exponential distribution is anything different from its rate?

Comment: @Did If you are new to mathematical statistics or distribution theory, then a text like Spanos _Probability Theory_ ... is a good entry point. Or try pick up a copy of Evans, Hastings & Peacocks summary _Statistical Distributions_. For encyclopaedic coverage of distributions, I'd recommend the Johnson, Kotz, Balakrishnan _Continuous Univariate Distributions_ volumes. Or perhaps Stuart and Ord's _Kendall's Advanced Theory of Statistics_.  ALL OF THESE STANDARD reference texts use the Exponential($a$) parameter as 1/rate.

Comment: @wolfies Spanos *Probability theory and statistical inference: econometric modeling with observational data* uses uniformly the rate as the parameter of exponential distributions (every 4 times on 4 the thing is used in the book, all in chapter 3) and **once** as the inverse of the parameter in Appendix A2 "Continuous univariate distributions". Forbes C., Evans M., Hastings N., Peacock B. (no "s" at the end) *Statistical distributions* use the scale parameter in the formulas of the characteristics of the exponential distributions .../...

Comment: .../... but, of course, they take care to immediately mention what they call the "alternative parameter λ, the hazard function (hazard rate), λ = 1/b". Etc. ALL IN ALL, these exemples confirm that your unwarranted attack on the OP (despite their unambiguous formulation "with parameter a, the expectation is 1/a") was "really" unjustified.

Comment: @Did Thank you for confirming that the above texts do both use the _scale_ definition and the _rate_ definition. This is contrary to your earlier assertion:

$$\text{Did wrote:}\\\text{Really? You might want to provide examples of mathematical sources where}\\\text{the "parameter" of an exponential distribution is anything different from its rate?}$$

I am pleased that you have come around to my original point: namely that there are two competing parameterisations in popular usage.

Comment: @wolfies "Assertions" are not usually ended by question marks. Combative mood, eh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find 
$$\int_0^\infty (x^4)ae^{-ax}\,dx.$$
A few integrations by parts!

If you will have a number of problems of this kind for an exponentially distributed random variable $X$, or maybe even if you won't, it might be useful to compute the [**moment generating function**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) $M_X(t)=E(e^{tX})$. This is
$$\int_0^\infty e^{tx}ae^{-ax}\,dx=\int_0^\infty a e^{-(a-t)x}\,dx.$$
Once you have done this (and it is a simple substitution) you can read off $E(X^n)$ for every positive integer $n$. 
By the way, the moment generating function is given by
$$M_X(t)=\frac{1}{1-\frac{t}{a}}.$$
The power series for this is easy to write down, it is just $1+w+w^2+w^3+\cdots$ where $w=\frac{t}{a}$. Now you might want to see what this tells you about $E(X^4)$, as a check on the integrations by parts.

The coefficient of $t^n$ in the expansion of $M_X(t)$ is $\dfrac{1}{a^n}$, so the $n$-th moment, that is, $E(X^n)$, is $\dfrac{n!}{a^n}$.